# Abp.io 7 Change IdentityUser password rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, abp, .net-7.0

In abp.io 7, .net 7, how to update password rules (like RequiredLength, RequireNonAlphanumeric, RequireUppercase, etc...) on creating identityuser using IIdentityUserAppService, or on using IdentityManager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find 2 problems :

1. Change password rules for **IIdentityUserAppService** > solution :

```
public class XXXSettingDefinitionProvider : SettingDefinitionProvider
{
    public override void Define(ISettingDefinitionContext context)
    {
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequiredUniqueChars, "6"));
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequireDigit, false.ToString()));
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric, false.ToString()));
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequireLowercase, false.ToString()));
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequireUppercase, false.ToString()));
        context.Add(new SettingDefinition(IdentitySettingNames.Password.RequiredUniqueChars, "0"));
    }
}
```

2. Change password rules for **IdentityUserManager** > Solution : (in XXXAplicationModule)

```
Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        });
```

Hope that's help someone :)